# Bounded non-constant holomorphic function on the complex plane minus the negative real axis

Tags: complex-analysis

I was recently given this question which I wasn't sure how to answer:

> Define
>   \begin{align*}
> \mathbb{R}_- = \left\{x \in \mathbb R \mid x < 0 \right\}
> \end{align*}
>   and let $D = \mathbb C \setminus \mathbb R_-$be  the set of all complex numbers that are not in $\mathbb R_-$. Give an explicit example of a bounded non-constant holomorphic function on the domain D. Explain why your function is bounded.

I know a function, e.g. the root $\sqrt z$, which is defined on exactly this domain $D$ (just take one of the eight possible root functions for the complex plane), but I don't think this function is bounded. Should I take $z^{-1/2}$ since it goes to zero at infinity? I'm very confused and now sure how to approach this question.

Comment: Note that as $z \to 0$, $z^{-1/2} \to \infty$.

Comment: @Travis Yeah, in retrospect that function won't do me much good either.

Comment: I assume you mean $D$ to be $\Bbb C - \{x \in \Bbb R \mid x \leq 0\}$, so that $D$ is open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** Since $D$ is a simply connected, nonempty, proper, open subset of $\Bbb C$, it is [biholomorphic to the unit disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_mapping_theorem).

Comment: Maybe this is obvious but how do I go from this to the explicit form of my function?

Comment: There /is/ a procedure for constructing such a map for any such subset (and it is hardly "obvious"), but the hint is really just supposed to be a reminder that one string together standard conformal maps to give biholomorphisms between various subsets of $\Bbb C$. Do you know a biholomorphism from the half-plane to the unit disk, for example?

Comment: Are you referring to the Cayley transform?

Comment: I like your answer and I can totally see the *existence* argument (you already have my upvote). I am, however, still battling the issue of making the function explicit... The question suggests I should already know this, but I am not even remotely seeing any possible candidates. I'm only aware of mappings which coincide with the given domain, but are *not* bounded.

Comment: Yes, I mean the Cayley transform, though for purposes of this problem, it saves us just a moment to work with the Cayley transform (post)composed with a clockwise rotation by $\frac{\pi}{2}$, which maps the *right* half-plane to the unit disc. This composition is the map $z \mapsto \frac{z - 1}{z + 1}$. With this in hand, we only need to find a biholomorphism between $D$ and the right half-plane. Can you think of such a map?

Comment: I suspect this to be the square root function for the domain $D$, but I still have to admit that I don't understand what is being asked of me, so I don't understand why this is the answer..

Comment: Do you mean, you don't know what a biholomorphism is, or you don't understand some aspect of your (original) question as you wrote it?

Comment: The biholomorphism is dandy but I don't understand the original question.  So I understand we want to use a function from some domain to another domain, but I don't understand for instance why, if the output (i.e. the "mapping")  of the function is bounded, then so is the  function itself. Maybe I'm just being silly here....

Comment: That's exactly what it means for a mapping (function) into $\Bbb C$ to be bounded: Its image is a bounded set.

Comment: I think this was the source of the confusion. Thanks for your help. Answer accepted.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found it helpful!